# How do I fret this "pattern"?

Tags: fingering, fretboard

I'm going through the beginning of a guitar arrangement of the first movement of Moonlight Sonata, and I'm not sure how to fret the bass notes in some cases.

For instance, there's a part where I fret an Am chord and fret an F# on the low E. It's a terrible stretch for the pinky finger, and I end up muting a few other strings.

Am I doing it right? If so, how do I do it properly?

(Bonus question: is Moonlight Sonata always played transposed on the guitar? If no, should I learn an "original" version?)

Answer (score 6):

I don't have my guitar with me right now. but it's probably easier to fret the F# with either your thumb, or to use the 2nd finger on f#, either that or the following:

```
--
-1- 1st
-2- 4th
-2- 3rd
--
-2- 2nd
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Exactly as I was writing, with the addendum that using the thumb is not "proper" classical technique, if attaining such a thing is a goal of the asker's.

Comment: There's an illustration of using the thumb like this in [Sor's Méthode Complète pour la Guitare](http://music.stackexchange.com/a/10201/1344).

Comment: @luserdroog man, that guy is totally pulling a metal face >:(